# SQL regex that excludes non-alphabets

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am writing a `sql` query to look through list of urls. I only have very limited knowledge in regex and I have never used it in SQL.

Say there is a table called `website` and there is a column called `url`

what I am trying to do is I want to find url that has the word `act`.

```
select *
from website
where url like '%act%'
```

But I realized I do not want any alphabetical character right before or after the word `act`.

I know regex can give me what I need, but I just can't figure out how to use it in sql syntax.

Comment: Which DBMS are you running? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.?

Comment: I am running on (Microsoft?) SQL server

Comment: Which version ?

Comment: Something like `WHERE ' ' + url + ' ' LIKE '%[^a-z]act[^a-z]%'`?

Comment: the version is ''sql server 2014'

Answer (score 1):

If you want *only* alphabetical characters in the string, then:

```
where url like '%act%' and url not like '%[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

If you only care about the characters just before and after:

```
where url like '%[^a-zA-Z]act[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

Comment: i did "where rawurl like '%[a-zA-Z]act[a-zA-Z]%'",
but I am still getting urls that has the word "practice", which includes the word "act" but it's got alphabetical character both before and after.

Comment: Put ^ in front of the a in both brackets. [^a-zA-Z] @HiJaeKim

Comment: @HiJaeKim . . . That was a typo.  There should be a negation on the character sets.